# Java Cron4J Persistent Task

Tags: java, tomcat, cron, persistence, task

Currently i'm running a nightly server task which was developed in Java using Cron4J. Now i chose Cron4J over the standard Java.util.Timer because of its persistence running the task even after the server has crashed or shut down.

However i cannot seem to shut the task off completely. I can manage to stop it while it is running, however it starts right back up when the server gets restarted.

Has anyone had any experience using the Cron4J library? I would like to be able to kill all sleeping tasks if it is possible.

Developing on: Windows 7, Apache Tomcat 7, JDK 6.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you called [deschedule](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/manual.php#p03) and that didn't remove the task from the queue? You will have to call it for ALL sleeping tasks, there is no way to say *cancel every single sleeping task*. If you put all your tasks in a file you can [descheduleFile](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/cron4j/Scheduler.html#descheduleFile%28java.io.File%29), which may be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There's really not a whole lot of help offered on this subject as i have put it on many boards. So i appreciate the advice. :)